# Expect condition inside the .then won't execute

Tags: angularjs, promise, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm using PageObjects in Protractor tests. 
Structure looks like this,

- e2e

  - specs

    - base.po.ts // Base PageObject class
    - Login

      - login.e2e-spec.ts // contains **describe**, **it** blocks etc. and Expect conditions.
      - login.po.ts // Interacts with page elements

I'm returning Promises from  methods inside **PageObject** file. And then inside **spec** file in **it** blocks i've **Expect** conditions.

A sample code is like,

```
// login.e2e-spec.ts

    it('should logout', () => {
          console.log('---- step 1 ----');
          page.logout().then(function () {
              console.log('---- step 4 ----');
              expect(page.inDom(page.getLoginButton())).toBe(true);
          });
          console.log('---- step 5 ----');
    });



// login.po.ts
public logout() {
        const that = this;
        return new Promise(function (fulfill = null, reject = null) {
            that.clickIfElementIsAvailable(that.welcomeModelCancelButtonElement);
            that.waitForVisibility(that.sideBarOpenerElement).then(function () {
                console.log('---- step 2 ----');
                that.sideBarOpenerElement.click();

                that.waitForVisibility(that.logoutButtonElement).then(function () {
                    console.log('---- step 3 ----');
                    that.logoutButtonElement.click();
                    fulfill();

                }, reject);

            }, reject);
        });
    }
```

After execution, all the tests pass and i get following output in log.

```
---- step 1 ----
---- step 5 ----
(node:2639) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForElement' of undefined
(node:2639) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
.


3 specs, 0 failures
```

In practical i've multiple tests so control just moves to next tests and at the end tells that all tests passed successfully.

Now i understand that control is putting the commands in queue and moving forward. How can i handle this situation? What i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It appears as though the error is coming from either your `clickIfElementIsAvailable`, or `waitForVisibility` function. Could you post those?

Comment: better if you write page object by using `async/await`. http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects#with-page-objects

Comment: @jithinkmatthew : Thanks. I tried it with async/await but nothing changed. I'm doubtful about using await condition when i've promises inside promises. For example, If i just use await  with that.waitForVisibility(that.sideBarOpenerElement) then will it be enough for all the code (including promises) inside .then block?

await that.waitForVisibility(that.sideBarOpenerElement).then(function () {
.......
});

Comment: Solved it by using RETURN statement on each promise. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4787

Answer (score 0):

I also posted the issue on Protractor github repository and got [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4787) solution from **IgorSasovets**

Use Return statement on each Promise. Current code looks like this,

```
public logout() {
    const that = this;
    return that.clickIfElementIsAvailable(that.welcomeModelCancelButtonElement)
        .then(() => that.waitForVisibility(that.sideBarOpenerElement))
        .then(() => {
            console.log('---- step 2 ----');
            return that.sideBarOpenerElement.click();
        })
        .then(() => that.waitForVisibility(that.logoutButtonElement))
        .then(() => {
            console.log('---- step 3 ----');
            return that.logoutButtonElement.click();
        });
}



it('should logout', () => {
      console.log('---- step 1 ----');
      return page.logout().then(() => {
          console.log('---- step 4 ----');
          expect(page.inDom(page.getLoginButton())).toBe(true);
          console.log('---- step 5 ----');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the promise before verifying the value in expect
some

page.getLoginButton().then(function(status){

expect(status).toBe(true);
})